# Change object property

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class

```
class Menu {
public:
    vector<MenuItem> currentMenu;

    void init();

    void show();

    void trigger();
};
```

And

```
class MenuItem {
private:
    std::string text;
    Menu link;

public:
    MenuItem(Menu &menu, string &text);

    string getText();

    void onEnter();
};
```

In MenuItem constructor i pass reference to Menu and store it in MenuItem property (Menu link;). And when try to clear Menu property (vector currentMenu;)

```
void MenuItem::onEnter() {
    this->link.currentMenu.clear();
}
```

Nothing change. How to change Menu property?

Comment: `link` needs to be a pointer or a reference otherwise it will just be a copy of `menu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MenuItem {
private:
    std::string text;
    Menu link;
...
```

Your link variable is declared as an instance of `Menu`. The constructor, makes a copy of `menu` in `link`.

Try to change `Menu link` with `Menu& link`

```
MenuItem::MenuItem(Menu &menu, string &_text)
 : link(menu)
 , text(_text)
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

the Menu variable in MenuItem should be of type Menu&. when you are currently storing the Menu object, it only stores a copy of Menu.